# How to generate control level events automatically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, c#-4.0

I have worked in `silverlight` and in `silverlight` I can create control level events automatically on `XAML`, but I am unable to do that in `.aspx page`.

Following are the examples to give clear idea.

`Silverlight`:
If I want to create a new event on `TextBlock` called `KeyDown`, `silverlight` gives me an option called `"<New Event Handler>"` which will automatically generate respected event in `.cs file` .

[image]

`Asp.NET`:
If I want to create an `OnClick` event on `button` than I don't have any option.

[image]

If I go to `design` page where my button is located and do double click than event is populating on `.cs page` but I want to do that on `source` in .aspx page.

Am I missing something here? I think there shouldn't be any difference in this scenario but I am not sure why I am not getting auto event generate option.

I am using `VS 2010` and `.NET Framework 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2010 doesn't auto create the event in ASP.NET. You can either manually create it, or upgrade to [VS 2013](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) (which may be free depending on which version you want/are eligible for).

The event signature is often

```
protected void MyControlId_EventName(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

but of course you can look up the specifics on MSDN. A notable exception is some of the GridView event handlers.

Comment: You're right. I just did a quick test in VS 2012 where I can see that option. In my opinion this sucks but anyways I found the solution so thank you for your help.

Comment: @Robinhood I agree it's inconvenient. But there's very few reasons to be sticking with older versions of VS, as they rarely drop support for old frameworks in newer versions.